# How to reduce vocabulary using tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, tokenize, word-embedding

I'm using `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer` to build a vocabulary for my corpus (5 million documents). The tokenizer finds 145K tokens. The issue is that the embedding layer has far too many parameters.

What's a simple way to force the tokenizer to only consider the top N most common words? Then anything outside of that would get a .

## Solution

As indicated by @MarcoCerliani in the comment, you can simply change the `num_words` parameter in the tokenizer. That won't change the tokenizer's internal data - it'll instead return `OOV` tokens for words outside the range specified by `num_words`.

```
tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(oov_token='<OOV>')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(huge_corpus)

len(tokenizer.word_counts)
>>> (some huge vocabulary size)

# Change vocabulary size
tokenizer.num_words = 100

tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)
>>> (any words in `texts` not within 100 most common words
>>>  will get `1` (out of vocab).
```

Comment: are you looking for num_words parameters? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer